# Bootstrap 3, list within a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set up a two-column layout - The left column is a list of items and the 2nd column is the details about an item in the first column (click on the item and the data renders, but that's not important right now).

I'm getting stuck setting up the layout - I can get the columns going, but when I add the list into the first column, it's rendering below it. And I'm not sure why.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-4">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a class="list-group-item">Item Here</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item">Item Here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main" class="col-md-8">
                Other Stuff Here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried removing the parent div (id="sidebar") and making that ID/width part of the list-group div, but then id="main" renders above the list.

So, I'm confused. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you "adding to the list"? It looks fine here: http://www.bootply.com/covyy95Cyd

Comment: if you use col-md, your div have 100% width below < 768px, so change `col-md` by `col-xs` for have your result for any device size

Comment: @Skelly it's part of a bootstrap application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use col-md, your div have 100% width when your browser width is below < 768px, it's a behavior on mobile first css grid, so change `col-md` by `col-xs` for have your result for any device size